# Want to prevent a textbox from becoming empty with javascript

Tags: javascript

So i already have a textbox in which you can only enter numbers and they have to be within a certain range.The textbox defaults to 1,and i want to stop the user from being able to make it blank.Any ideas guys?Cheers

```
                    <SCRIPT language=Javascript>

       window.addEventListener("load", function () {
        document.getElementById("quantity").addEventListener("keyup", function (evt) {
            var target = evt.target;

             target.value = target.value.replace(/[^\d]/, "");
              if (parseInt(target.value, 10) > <%=dvd5.getQuantityInStock()%>) {
                target.value = target.value.slice(0, target.value.length - 1);
           }
        }, false);
              });


               <form action="RegServlet"  method="post"><p>Enter quantity you would  like to purchase :
<input name="quantity" id="quantity" size=15 type="text" value="1" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use your `onkeyup` listener to check if the input's value is empty. Something along the lines of:

```
if(target.value == null || target.value === "")
    target.value = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a function to validate the form when the text box loses focus. I ported the following code at http://forums.asp.net/t/1660697.aspx/1, but it hasn't been tested:

```
document.getELementById("quantity").onblur = function validate() {
    if (document.getElementById("quantity").value == "") {
            alert("Quantity can not be blank");
            document.getElementById("quantity").focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. save the text when `keydown`
2. check empty when `keyup`, if empty, restore the saved text, otherwise update the saved text.
3. And you could try the new `type="number"` to enforce only number input

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gongzhitaao/VBreF/1/)